# Router configuration such that all devices get network IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ip, wireless-router

> I am planning to set up a router in my institute hostel room.

I currently use a LAN cable provided and plug it into my laptop to access internet. The steps are:

```
1. Connect LAN cable to laptop
2. Go to 192.168.1.211 and enter college user ID and password
```

On doing this I get the following parameters on my laptop:

```
1. IP Address: 192.168.214.141

2. Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0

3. Default gateway: 192.168.214.1
```

Now I bought a router and am planning to connect it to the wall LAN cable and use internet from there.

If I have a normal (DHCP) setting, then I won't be able to connect to 192.168.1.211 as my router will create a local pool of IP addresses.

I want to set up the router such that the router doesn't have an IP address and every device connected to the router will get IP on the institute network, and not a local network. I just want to be able to access 192.168.1.211

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that merely having different addresses will prevent you from connecting to 192.168.1.211? The whole Internet has different addresses and that doesn't prevent you from reaching those sites.

Comment: The router creates a pool from 192.168.xxx.xxx right?

Answer (score 0):

*Just an FYI, your college's IT department likely has a HowTo on the college's webserver*

If devices:

- Don't need an individually assigned 192.168.214.0/24 address to access the college's network:

  - Configure WAN for DHCP and LAN with an appropriate RFC1918 IP *([Page 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918))*.

    - This will result in a double NAT'd environment, which will create issues for gaming, and/or any other services requiring port redirects.
  - All devices behind the router will present to the college's network with the IP assigned to the router's WAN port
- Need an individually assigned 192.168.214.0/24 address to access the college's network:

  - It's possible consumer routers running OEM firmware may not support this, as your WAN and LAN will both need to be set to receive DHCP addresses from WAN *(i.e. WAN and LAN will need to be bridged)*

    - Bridging LAN and WAN effectively makes the router a Smart Switch
    - The only way this would work without bridging is if the IT department provides you with static IPs for all devices behind the router.
  - If this option is required, and you're unsure how to do so on your router, reach out to the college's IT department, as they should be able to help you.

Comment: Apparently, I'm the first person to get a router in my hostel room in the entire college. There isn't a how-to for this, I checked. Also, my router is D-Link DIR 615. It probably doesn't support bridged mode, I'm not sure.

Comment: As there are more than 256 students in the hostel, i think 192.168.214.0/24 isn't required? Could there be 192.168.xxx.xxx as well?

Comment: The D-Link DIR 615 is supported by [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/toh/d-link/dir-615), which allows bridging of WAN & LAN via a vLAN _(it would be a good idea to flash OpenWrt to it anyways since that device has likely reached its EoL)_.  The subnet you were assigned to is 192.168.214.0/24, which allows for 253 client IPs, assuming the DHCP server is on the same subnet (254 assignable IPs total).  It's likely different subnets and vLANs are configured for the college's intranet, with certain blocks made available for student devices.